# Power Bi - Add thousands separator to cards

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have some DAX which adds the thousands separator to my card totals which I use in a measure:

```
Add Separator Measure = 
VAR right =
    RIGHT ( [Card Total Measure], 3 )
VAR left =
    SUBSTITUTE ( [Card Total Measure] , right, "" )
RETURN
    COMBINEVALUES ( ",", left, right )
```

Only drawback is that when the total is 0 it keeps the thousands separator before the total e.g. (,£0).

How can I add some logic that will remove the separator if the total is 0 to the existing dax?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way to format a number.

The easiest thing to do is to use formatting controls under the Modeling tab.

[image: Formatting]

If that doesn't get you what you want, then the [`FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply however I require the dax to add the If logic to the above code.

Comment: The logic you have has other problems that adding an `IF` won't help. "1234123" becomes "4,123", for example, and it doesn't work for more than 6 digits.

Comment: An `IF(LEN([Card Total Measure]) < 4, [Card Total Measure], ...)` would help smaller numbers though.

Comment: This answer is on the right track with basic formatting, which would be default not leave a comma when the number is 0. You might try a SWITCH statement with FORMAT to make the formatting dynamic according to your conditions.