# DAX Measure IF statement with Variables

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have a dax measure that adds a thousands separator to my card totals in Power BI, converting them to a string (I am also including a currency symbol in another measure to the same card which is why it needs to be a string).

I want to add an if statement that will say if the total amount is < 1000, then remove the thousands separator from the total. Currently numbers like £500 appear with the separator before the total e.g.
,£500. Here is the code:

```
Card Total = 
VAR right =
    RIGHT ( [Total Amount], 3 )
VAR left =
    SUBSTITUTE ( [Total Amount] , right, "" )
RETURN
    COMBINEVALUES ( ",", left, right )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power Bi - Add thousands separator to cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339560/power-bi-add-thousands-separator-to-cards)

Answer (score 0):

The following measure will not include a comma when the total is under 1000.  I don't know how large the values you're working with are, but if they exceed 6 digits you'll also want to add additional commas where necessary.

```
Card Total = 
VAR RIGHT =
    RIGHT ( [Total Amount], 3 )
VAR LEFT =
    SUBSTITUTE ( [Total Amount] , RIGHT, "" )
RETURN
IF (
    [Total Amount] < 1000
    RIGHT,
    COMBINEVALUES ( ",", LEFT, RIGHT )
    )
```

Comment: The Total Amount measure is a string because I have joined a currency symbol to the total. Is it possible to adapt the above code to work with a string rather than an integer using VALUE or FORMAT functions? I tried adding "" to the 1000 however this just limits the total to three characters.